# Не компилируется код класса, разделённого на файлы .cpp и .h | C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

Создал простой класс, представляющий комплексное число. Пытаюсь добавить перезагрузку для вывода, но выдаёт гору ошибок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Complex.h:

```
#pragma once

class Complex
{
public:

    Complex(float real, float imagine);

    float get_real() const;

    float get_imagine() const;

    Complex operator+(const Complex& other) const;

    Complex operator-(const Complex& other) const;

    Complex operator*(const Complex& other) const;

private:
    float real, imagine;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Complex& complex);
```

Complex.cpp

```
#include "Complex.h"
#include <iostream>

Complex::Complex(float real = 0, float imagine = 0)
{
    this->real = real;
    this->imagine = imagine;
}

float Complex::get_real() const 
{
    return real;
}

float Complex::get_imagine() const 
{
    return imagine;
}

Complex Complex::operator+(const Complex& other) const
{
    return Complex(real + other.real, imagine + other.imagine);
}

Complex Complex::operator-(const Complex& other) const
{
    return Complex(real - other.real, imagine - other.imagine);
}

Complex Complex::operator*(const Complex& other) const
{
    return Complex(real * other.real - imagine * other.imagine,
        real * other.imagine + imagine * other.real);
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Complex& complex)
{
    return out << '(' << complex.get_real() << ", " << complex.get_imagine() << "i)";
}
```

main.cpp: стандартный с `hello world`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#include iostream` из `.cpp` перекинь в `.h`, ибо оно не определяет `ostream` в `.h` файле.

Comment: Можно даже `<ostream>` вместо `<iostream>`.

Comment: спасибо за помощь)